# How to check if an USB device is present without lsusb?

Tags: usb

I want to see if an USB device is present but I don't have lsusb.

Is there another way to check if an USB device is present without having to use lsusb?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
mount -t usbfs none /proc/bus/usb 
cat /proc/bus/usb/devices
```

If you don't have the `usbfs` module OR `/proc/bus/usb` directory,
then try this

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product
```

Comment: I see no `dev` in `/proc/bus/` I see only `input` and `pci`.

Comment: Great low level method, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
```

Comment: Unlike many of the other answers, this one requires `sudo` rights on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 5):

you can also try the command

```
$ usb-devices
```

It would give you something like this,

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 1
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-59-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:02:00.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2109 ProdID=3431 Rev=04.20
S:  Product=USB2.0 Hub
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-59-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:02:00.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-59-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:12.2
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-59-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:13.2
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=04 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=05e3 ProdID=0608 Rev=77.64
S:  Product=USB2.0 Hub
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=05 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12  MxCh= 3
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0001 Rev=03.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.19.0-59-generic ohci_hcd
S:  Product=OHCI PCI host controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:12.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=05 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04ca ProdID=0061 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=PixArt
S:  Product=USB Optical Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need to do and want to see. Exploration of the device entries under /sys/bus/usb might already prove to be sufficient.

Another way would be to use udev to manage specific actions on detection of a specific USB device. The web has numerous examples, but for example on insertion of a specific USB thumbdrive you can have udev create a device entry like /dev/MyThumbdrive instead of or in addition to /dev/sdd1.